# jquery replace div content with content from a url/link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with multiple divs, these are used to make tabs with jquery.

I am loading in external pages with php like mysql data with pagination etc.

what i want is when a user clicks a link in each div it replaces the div with content from that url.

e.g.

```
<div id="home">
<a href="home1.php">Home1</a>
<a href="home2.php">Home2</a>
</div>

<div id="music">
<a href="track.php?tid=1">Track 1</a> - <a href="artist.php?aid=3">Artist</a>
<a href="music.php">First</a> <a href="music.php?page=1">Page 1</a> <a href="music.php?page=2">Page 2</a> 
</div>
```

so when i click home1 it replaces the home div with home1.php
when i click page 1 it replaces music div with music page 1 etc.

How do i do this? i have been looking at jquery click() and replacewith() but have not yet worked out how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You really need to work on your accepted questions rate - 6 questions and you have accepted 0 answers have a read of these http://stackoverflow.com/faq and you will see why its important to you and others to accept answers ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach an event to the links you want this feature active on - you can do that by either adding a class to the links - ie

```
<div id="home">
<a class="livelink" href="home1.php">Home1</a>
<a class="livelink" href="home2.php">Home2</a>
</div>

<div id="music">
<a class="livelink" href="track.php?tid=1">Track 1</a> - <a class="livelink" href="artist.php?aid=3">Artist</a>
<a class="livelink" href="music.php">First</a> <a class="livelink" href="music.php?page=1">Page 1</a> <a class='"livelink" href="music.php?page=2">Page 2</a> 
</div>
```

And then binding the `click` event to all those anchors :

```
$('.livelink').click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent('div').load($(this).attr('href')); //load the data
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from following the link
});
```

or by activating all links

```
$('div a').click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent('div').load($(this).attr('href'));
  event.preventDefault; // prevent the browser from following the link
});
```

I think you are better using the first method as you have more control

Answer (score 1):

There is a [possible] problem with your thinking: when either home1.php or home2.php is loaded into the "home" div, that new content will overwrite those two links. That also goes to the "music" div. Is that what you really want?

As a matter of fact, as you have it, when the client click on Home1 or Home2, the browser is going to load those pages as you have them as href anchors.

You might want to try something in this line:

```
<div "home">
 <span style='display:block; ' onClick="$('#home').load('home1.php'); ">Home1</span>
 <span style='display:block; ' onClick="$('#home').load('home2.php'); ">Home2</span>
</div>
```

If you do not want to overwrite the links inside "home", you might want to add new divs for home1 and home2 right below the two links for example.

EDIT (per request) - disabling the onClick and adding a loading gif

```
<div "home">
 <span id='home1' style='display:block; ' onClick='showHomeOne(); ' >Home1</span>
 <span id='home2' style='display:block; ' onClick='showHomeTwo(); ' >Home2</span>
 <span id='home1Content' style='margin-top:4px; display:none; ' ></span>
 <span id='home2Content' style='margin-top:4px; display:none; ' ></span>
</div>
<!-- 
 in a more advanced mode, you could do showHome('1') and showHome('2')
--->

function showHomeOne() {
    if ($('#home1Content').is(':hidden') == false) return;
    // the above line works as a virtual onClick disable
    // in case the home1Content is already being displayed

    $('#home1Content').html('<img src=\'your-loading-gif.gif\' />').toggle();
    // the \' is because I am using single quotes within single-quotes
    // I could avoid this by using the double quotes on either of the sets
    // Thel toggle() will toggle from display:none to display:'' and make
    // the span visible.

    $('#home1Content').load('home1.html');
    // when the page home1.html is load, it automatically will overwrite the gif
}

This is it! Do the same for home2. Only your creativity and knowledge is the limit
to what you can do in jQuery.

Assumed that there are no extra processing to display the pages, you could use the 
version below for ALL the pages:

Change the onClick to onCLick='showPage(\'pageID-of-your-choosing\'); '

function showPage(pageID) {
    //make sure to change the hidden span IDs accordingly:

    if ($('#'+pageID+'Content').is(':hidden') == false) return;

    $('#'+pageID+'Content').html('<img src=\'your-loading-gif.gif\' />');

    $('#'+pageID+'Content').load(pageID+'.html');

    // for the last line you could replace it with a nested if:
    // var myHtml;
    // if (pageID == 'home1')
    //     myHtml='home1.html'
    // else if (pageID == 'home2')
    //     myHtml='home2.html'
    // else if (pageID == 'home3')
    //     myHtml='home3.html'
    // else if (pageID == 'music1')
    //     myHtml='music1.html'
    // else if (pageID == 'abcdefghig')
    //     myHtml='the-page-that-would-be-called-in-this-case.html';
    // --> notice the ; at the end of the last line above: end of statement
    //
    // $('#'+pageID+'Content').load(myHtml);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: so far this is doing what i want well. how can i disable the onclick after first click as suggested below and possibly show a loading image? cheers.

Comment: Please vote the question up and accept my answer. That would improve my points. I will be adding to the solution as an EDIT:

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably want jQuery's `.load(url);` method, have a look at the API doc here:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would like to use the jQuery ajax function 'load'
http://api.jquery.com/load/

I would think your onclick should look like this

```
onclick="loadParentWith(this)"
```

and somewhere you should have

```
function loadParentWith(link){
    $(link).parent('div').load($(link).attr('href'));
}
```

Just to let you know you may want to think about possibly disabling the link after the first click so that you don't try to load the same div multiple times. If somebody with a slow connection uses your page they may click on it 2 - 3 times before the first response comes back.

Comment: Don't use onlick, attach jQuery events.

Comment: I don't see any markup that can be safely selected to attach events with, unless you propose attaching to every single anchor tag inside a div. Other than that I agree as you can easily unbind the event after first click

Comment: If you can add an onlick, you can cadd a class. ManseUKs answer has done it :)